# Laravel livewire: update text field based on first field value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm struggling to understand how `livewire` works.

I have two text fields. One is where the user enters information like prefixes and the second field with a `read-only` attribute where data will be displayed based on the first field value.
But for some reason, I can't populate the second field. All examples on the internet are how to take a value and return it back or generate a dropdown menu.

my `blade` template:

```
<div class="mb-3">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">prefix</label>
     <input  wire:change="testing"
             type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="prefix"
             name="prefix"
     />
 </div>
 <div class="mb-3">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Code</label>
     <input  wire:model="part"
             type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="part"
             name="part"
             value="{{ $part }}"
     />
 </div>
```

and
`Livewire` `class`:

```
class DoSomethingClass extends Component
{
    public $prefix;
    public $part;


    public function testing()
    {

        $this->part = $this->prefix;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.blade-template');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should make use of wire:model to the first property. Than make a listener for that property that changes the second property, also bound with wire:model.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wire:model` to **both input fields**. Than, if you want to update the 2nd field on the input of the first, you can use the Livewire Lifecycle to update it.

```php
    public $prefix;

    public $part;

    public function updatedPrefix()
    {
        $this->part = $this->prefix;
    }
```

Check this link for info on the updatedPrefix() hook: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks

(You can choose to use your testing() method too, but than you still need to use the wire:model directive to your second input.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make what you're doing work just by adding `wire:model="prefix"` to your first `input` as suggested above.

```php
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">prefix</label>
    <input  wire:change="testing"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="prefix"
            name="prefix"
            wire:model="prefix"
    />
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Code</label>
    <input  wire:model="part"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="part"
            name="part"
            value="{{ $part }}"
    />
</div>
```

And the component itself can just stay the same. When someone types anything in the first field then tabs or clicks away it will update the second field.

If you want the second field to update as the user types change it to `wire:keydown="testing"`, it will make a call with every keystroke.

```php
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">prefix</label>
    <input  wire:keydown="testing"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="prefix"
            name="prefix"
            wire:model="prefix"
    />
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Code</label>
    <input  wire:model="part"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="part"
            name="part"
            value="{{ $part }}"
    />
</div>
```

As mentioned above, if you use the `updatedPrefix()` method you won't need the `wire:change` or `wire:keydown` as Livewire will update the field as the user types.